# Get a google's email/username in java?

Tags: java, oauth, google-oauth

is it possible to retrieve the username of a google account that i have succesfully authenticated using OAuth?

i have retrieved the users Access tokens but i am wondering if their is a API call i can make such has https://google.api/getUserName and pass the access tokens to that call and succesfully retrieve the users email/username?

In a normal OAuth web service, all you need is the secret and id access tokens to make calls to the web service but in google you also need the username too.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Daniel  S/He is demonstration call.

Comment: Yes tahts correct, i was only demonstrating the call to see if their is something similar for google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/Home/emaildisplayscope .  That should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I figured so far is using the Spreadsheet API.

If you request the feed, that lists all documents

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full?alt=json

There is a field with the username as well:

```
response.data.feed.title.$t
```

Unfortunately, this means prompting the user to grant access to his GDocs account, which may be confusing..

But I don't know of any API by Google to directly get the username.

Comment: its strange how google needs the oauth tokens as well as the username

Answer (score 1):

Best way, the following feed was retrieved from the Contacts Data API:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=0

and get next fields from the feed:

```
response.data.feed.id
```

or

```
response.data.feed.author.name.$t
response.data.feed.author.email.$t
```

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/intl/ja/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html#Errors

**This one is PHP, i think a slight modification in JAVA could make this workout**

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/google-analytics-login-php-curl-username-password/

Comment: That wont work properly as i have to temporarily store a users account credentials to send it to google to login which defeats the purpose of Oauth.

What i want is a simple API call i could make to google that returns me who is the username behind the OAUTH tokens i have retieved via OAUTH.